# Keep div and its children fixed when scrolling

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

When user scrolls, how to set upper div fixed so that lower div will pass over him? I don't know what will be the height of image.
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oxOPXv

```
// Stays in position
<div class="col-md-12 top-wrapper">
  <div class="container image-wrapper">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/750x550" />
  </div>
</div>

// moving up and over .top-wrapper (also other content below this)
<div class="bottom-wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-3 sidebar">
      <p>Lorem</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9 main-div">
      <p>Lorem</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Not sure about all bootstrap possibilities, but, since you have jQuery, and image height is dynamic... this (maybe) could help: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oxOPBg

Answer (score 1):

You spelled "position" wrong in your css.  You left the last "i" out.  It should be:

```
.top-wrapper {
  background-color: #eee;
 position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: True, that was when I tried to set up code on Codepen. But the question still remains because this is breaking everything, header and lower content :)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding this correctly, the `.top-wrapper` is fixed and you want everything else to be able to scroll up and over `.top-wrapper`. Since there's not enough content to cause your divs to become taller, you won't have enough room to actually scroll that high. You can increase your vertical space by doing this:

```
body {
  height: 250vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

[**CODEPEN**](http://codepen.io/zer00ne/pen/QNPVgm?editors=1100)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this?: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dMLqdM

I fixed (i.e. `position: fixed;`) not only the '.top-wrapper', but also the 'header', and in addition gave the '.top-wrapper' a `margin-top: 50px;` to position it below the header. (I also added some more content to the bottom wrapper to make the scrolling more obvious)